# If I install Xubuntu desktop

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, desktop-environments

Are there any conflicts with installing different Desktop environments in Ubuntu ?

I have already installed Gnome-Shell and can't log-out the session to switch DE.

I have to reboot to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly your problem with GNOME might be, but to answer your general question: You can have different DEs in Ubuntu (and Linux in general) without any problems.

Only when using PPAs, you sometimes can run into trouble with library dependcies and stuff.

Comment: The log-out problem stopped after a reboot

Comment: Have you checked it? At least in 13.10 Unity and Gnome-shell had a lot of problems togheter --- shared settings behaved weirdy. I *think* that things are better now, but I had such a mess that I didn't checked in 14.04 and went with Gnome alone.

Comment: I haven't checked every DE and every Ubuntu version, but it would be a sad day for this multi user system if not. I've been using 12.04 on a shared computer as well as 14.04. At least 14.04 was used with xfce, gnome and KDE, 12.04 had similar DEs.